# How to convert date part of datetime to timestamp in PHP?

Tags: php, timestamp

How can I just convert date part of datetime to timestamp?

For example in this datetime: 2018-02-26 20:30:00

I want timestamp of 2018-02-26 00:00:00.

Comment: Can you transform the datetime? If you do `$datetime->setTime(0, 0, 0)` you will have the `2018-02-26 00:00:00` format you want no?

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer using the DateTime API you could also do:

```
$dateAndTime = '2018-02-26 20:30:30';    
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateAndTime)->setTime(0, 0)->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use substr you only need to use strtotime once and no date.

```
Echo strtotime(substr("2018-02-26 20:30:00",0,10));
```

Or you can use explode:

```
Echo strtotime(explode(" ", "2018-02-26 20:30:00")[0]);
```

I explode on space and use the first item `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.  Just use strtotime twice.  Once to set your date and then the second to generate the timestamp.

strtotime() can be used to convert just about any human readable date string to a timestamp.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
$str = '2018-02-26 20:30:30';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($str)) . '<br>';

echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($str)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

echo strtotime(date("Y-m-d",strtotime("2018-02-26 20:30:00"))." 00:00:00");
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy and best solution would be this one:

```
$datetime = '2018-02-26 20:30:00';

$new_date = strtotime( Date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $datetime ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date = "2018-02-26 20:30:00";
echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $date));
```

This outputs UNIX timestamp. You can remove `strtotime` to get gregorian calendar